# How to make multiple page IDs simpler (array?)

Tags: wordpress

The simple code below:

```
<?php
    $callout_1 = '1';
    $callout_2 = '3';
    $callout_3 = '5';
?>
<ul>
    <li><h3 class="title"><?php echo get_the_title($callout_1); ?></h3></li>
    <li><h3 class="title"><?php echo get_the_title($callout_2); ?></h3></li>
    <li><h3 class="title"><?php echo get_the_title($callout_3); ?></h3></li>
</ul>
```

I have lots of more stuff inside the `<li>` tags, but all has the same structure, the above sample is just an example. Can anyone help me to make it easier please?

**Edit:** Thanks for the answer Tamil, Can you help me on another question based on this please? If `1` then echo `text 1`, if `2` then echo `text 2` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array to store the page ids

Try

```
<?php $callout = array('1', '3', '5'); ?>
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($callout as $call) { 
?> 
<li><h3 class="title"><?php echo get_the_title($call); ?></h3></li> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a associative array. Its a multiple array having key=>value pair. Value is accessed by key.

```
 `$callouts = array(array('id'=>1, 'text'=>'text1'), array('id'=>2, 'text'=>'text2'),array('id'=>3, 'text'=>'text3'));`
```

So now while looping you can print both id and text.

```
foreach( $callouts as $call ) {
   echo '<li><h3>'.get_the_title($call['id']).'</h3></li>';
   echo '<p>'.$call['text'].'</p>';
}
```

If you have to get the value and store in array:

```
$ids = array('1','2','3');
$callouts = array();
foreach($ids as $id ){
  $title = get_the_title($id);
  if( $id == 1)
    $text = 'Text 1';
  elseif($id == 2)
    $text = 'Text 2';
  else
   $text = '';
  $callouts[] = array('id'=>$id, 'title'=>$title, 'text'=>$text);
}
```

To print, you can use single array to print everything.

```
foreach( $callouts as $call ){
   echo '<li><h3>'.$call['id'].'<h3></li>';
   echo '<li><h3>'.$call['title'].'<h3></li>';
   echo '<li><h3>'.$call['text'].'<h3></li>';
}
```

Hope this helps